# In Clojure, what is the difference between apply and into for transforming lazy seqs into other types?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, I frequently use the following code:

```
(into [] (range 3))
```

But then I've seen this code being used:

```
(apply vector (range 3))
```

What is the difference between those two code samples ? Is one more idiomatic than the other ? When to use into to init collections, and when to use apply + factory function ?

Comment: The latter I would write as `(vec (range 3))`. No need to use `apply` there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you are calling them, the results of both functions are the same. However, the semantics of `apply` and `into` are quite different.

- `apply` is used to eval a function received as an argument with a set of arguments, also received as arguments. `(apply vector (range 3))` results in a call to `(vector 0 1 2)`
- `into` reduces a collection into another by repeatedly applying `conj`. `(into [] (range 3))` results in `(conj (conj (conj [] 0) 1) 2)`.

Regarding which is more idiomatic, this enters into the realm of opinions. I would suggest to use whichever shows intent in your particular situation. I might use `into` for the specific use case you raise in the comment (building a concrete type from a lazy seq). I think it would be easier to read:

```
(into [] (get-the-lazy-seq))
;; vs
(apply vector (get-the-lazy-seq))
```

Last but not least, there might be differences on the memory footprint and performance of both invocations but they depend so much on your environment that I would recommend to use a profiler if you are concerned about this.

Comment: FYI: `(range 3)` yields `(0 1 2)`, but the spirit of your answer is spot on. :-)

Comment: But for my use case, which one is more idiomatic ? My use case being to build a concrete type from lazyseq.

Comment: @MMacphail I'd say into is more idiomatic for converting sequences.

Comment: @jszakmeister I would agree. I just edited the answer to add  my opinion about it.

Comment: @c-garcia Thanks I'll continue to use into. I was surprised to see the apply vector pattern in Rick's code himself: https://github.com/juliangamble/clojure-ants-simulation/blob/master/src/ants.clj